# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки страница поднималась вверх?

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки страница поднималась вверх?
Например, у меня AJAX (загрузка контента без перезагрузки страницы), и мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки страница поднималась вверх.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         ???????????????????????
     });
</script>

<a href="index.php">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Зачем делать на JQuery?Если можно просто сделать якорь?
<a href="#">Вверх</a>
Попробуй.

Comment: Анкор моментально перемещает, а не плавно скроллит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/vz2wryLb/2/

Comment: @mountpoint, Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Гуглить вообще лень, да?

```
$(function(){
  $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Не работаю с jQuery, но как-то так.

Comment: @TheDoctor, не работает! по моему нужно добавить типа a click

Comment: Так это пример!

Вот рабочий пример, надеюсь поймёшь: https://jsfiddle.net/vz2wryLb/1/

Comment: <code><a href="#">&uArr;</a></code> - тоже сработает без всяких джаваскриптов

Comment: @zhenyab, думаю ТС не зря "прозрачно намекнул" на то, что нужно использовать jQuery, смекаешь?

Comment: А без jQuery мы уж дышать не сможем. На jQuery свет клином сошелся. Я просто предложил альтернативный вариант, путь истинного джедая. Но если вопрошаюший адепт и фанат jQuery, то я, конечно, умываю ручки.

Comment: @zhenyab, понимаю, бро, понимаю, буквально сегодня на эту тему распинался [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/408626/javascript-как-для-всех-тегов-input-с-заданным-атрибутом-выставить-например-атрибут-checked-false).

Comment: @TheDoctor, Спасибо!